# Tons of generated "SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM ..." queries in MySQL connector/j

Tags: mysql, mysql-connector, spring-jdbc

I'm using Spring-jdbc NamedParameterJdbcTemplate with mysql-connector-j and I'm getting tons of "extra" SQL issued after almost every statement all of which looks like `"SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM ..."`.

Here's a piece of MySQL log that shows my query followed by lots of queries that I did not issue:

```
Query     SELECT p.*, t.textdata descr, ... from parts p, string t where .....
Query     SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM `mydb`.`parts`
Query     SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM `mydb`.`parts`
Query     SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM `mydb`.`parts`
Query     SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM `mydb`.`parts`
Query     SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM `mydb`.`parts`
Query     SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM `mydb`.`parts`
Query     SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM `mydb`.`parts`
Query     SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM `mydb`.`parts`
Query     SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM `mydb`.`parts`
Query     SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM `mydb`.`parts`
Query     SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM `mydb`.`parts`
Query     SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM `mydb`.`parts`
Query     SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM `mydb`.`parts`
Query     SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM `mydb`.`parts`
Query     SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM `mydb`.`parts`
Query     SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM `mydb`.`strings`
Query     SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM `mydb`.`strings`
```

Why is this happening and how do I stop it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some investigation it seems the issue is caused by poor implementation of [Field.getCollation()](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-connector-j/blob/5.1.35/src/com/mysql/jdbc/Field.java#L433) in mysql-connector which is called from `ResultSetMetaData.isCaseSensitive()` which in turn is called by `CachedRowSet` which is used by Spring jdbc.

Fortunately there is a quick workaround which is to set `useDynamicCharsetInfo` to `false` e.g.:

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost/mydb?useDynamicCharsetInfo=false
```

=== EDIT Dec 2015 ===

After abandoning the GPL-licensed MySQL-connector in favor of LGPL-licensed [MariaDB-connector](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/about-mariadb-connector-j/), this problem no longer exists.